# Rails Tutorial Chapter 8 tests expect Redirect return 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I've looked at similarly titled threads, but they don't have the exact same problem as this.

I'm working on the Rails 4 Tutorial. I'm on chapter 8. I'm using Cloud9's IDE. When I'm running the server and I log in directly on the website, it works just fine. But when I attempt the "login with valid information" test, which should turn up green, it doesn't.

I get this error.

```
FAIL["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 2015-05-10 20:30:40 +0000]
test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1431289840.31s)
    Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

which makes me think there's something wrong with my login credentials for the test, but I can't figure out where.

From the rails console I get the following:

```
>> User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", created_at: "2015-06-23 17:55:51", updated_at: "2015-06-23 18:52:37", password_digest: "$2a$10$Xl36B/1PmWJmsUOh3JBmnuQmhwLEIq1B5626jcW46fv...">
```

Here's my code:

test/integration/users_login_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test 'login with invalid information' do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test 'login with valid information' do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

test/fixtures/users.yml

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest("password") %>
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : 
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost 
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

I am completely stuck trying to figure this out.

added per request:
app/controllers/sessions_controler.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:passowrd])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' #Not quite right!
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Can we see your sessions controller?  It will help us understand what happens when a new session is created.

Comment: OMG. I misspelled password in the line
`if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:passowrd])`

It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [steve klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311657/steve-klein) for helping me find the answer. The problem was in the sessions controller.

```
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:passowrd])
```

A simple typo (password) was screwing me up.